# Integrate Sustainsys into Asp.net MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

Im currently trying to integrate Sustainsys into an existing ASP.Net MVC application. Im following the guide at https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/latest/configuration.html and have the following:

- **My application:** https://application.com
- **Login:** https://application.com/login
- **External application:** https://external.com
- **External application EntityID:** https://external.com
- **External application SAML assertion endpoint:** https://external.com:443/auth/saml
- **PFX File:** ~/App_Data/certificate.pfx

When the user authenticates into https://application.com/login , I want them to be authenticated to https://external.com (proprietary service we are using) as well. My question is how can this be done without an IdP with Sustainsys?

Comment: Any solution found?